# unable to carry over Class value under While loop for Python blackjack game

Tags: python

I am trying not to post a block of code, but essentially I was hoping to have players be able to bet X chips starting with 100, and you would eventually run out of chips or make a python fortune.

however, I have my chips class defined before the master While loop which I thought would allow the saved Chips value to keep adding or subtracting however this is not working. I also print the total chips value at the end when I ask the player again and the win/lose value is not even kept there.

I appreciate any help you can provide in why my chips are not being tracked of. the value is always the starting 100

the relevant classes/functions:

```
class Chips:

    def __init__(self):
        self.total=100
        self.bet = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return f'you have {self.total} chips, your bet was {self.bet}'

    def win_bet(self):
        self.total += self.bet

    def lose_bet(self):
        self.total -= self.bet

def take_bet(n):
    while True:
        try:
            chips=int(input('please provide a bet: '))
        except:
            print('not a number')
            continue
        else:
            break


def bust():
    if player_hand.value>21:
        player_chips.lose_bet()
        print('\nyou bust! dealer wins')



    if dealer_hand.value>21:
        player_chips.win_bet()
        print('\ndealer bust! player wins')


    if dealer_hand.value>player_hand.value and dealer_hand.value<=21:
        player_chips.lose_bet()
        print('\nDealer wins')



def push():
    if dealer_hand.value==player_hand.value:
        print('\npush! bet returned')

def play_again():
    play=input(f'do you wish to keep playing?\n\nplayer has {player_chips.total} chips \n\ntype "y" or "n"')
    if play.lower()=='y':
        clear_output()
        game=True
    if play.lower()=='n':
        clear_output()
        print('thanks for playing')
        game=False
```

then the game:

```
player_chips=Chips()
game=True
while game==True:
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()


    player_hand = Hand()
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())


    dealer_hand = Hand()
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())



    clear_output()
    print('output cleared')
    print('Welcome to blackjack')
    print(f'\nplayer has {player_chips.total} chips')
    take_bet(player_chips)

    x=True
    while x is True:
        show_initial(player_hand,dealer_hand)
        print('\nplayers hand value=',player_hand.value)
        hit_or_stand(deck,player_hand)
        if player_hand.value>21:
            clear_output()    
            show_all_player(player_hand)
            print('\nplayers hand value=',player_hand.value)
            bust()
            x=False
            break
        print('\nit is now the dealers turn')
        show_all_dealer(dealer_hand)
        print('\ndealers opening hand value=',dealer_hand.value)

        if player_hand.value<=21:

            while dealer_hand.value<player_hand.value:
                dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
                dealer_hand.adjust_for_ace()
                show_all_dealer(dealer_hand)
                print('\ndealers hand value=',dealer_hand.value)


                if dealer_hand.value>21:
                    bust()
                    x=False
                    break
                if dealer_hand.value<17:
                    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
                    dealer_hand.adjust_for_ace()
            if dealer_hand.value==player_hand.value:
                push()
                x=False
                break
            if dealer_hand.value>player_hand.value:
                bust()
                x=False
                break

    play=input(f'do you wish to keep playing?\n\nplayer has {player_chips.total} chips \n\ntype "y" or "n"')
    if play.lower()=='y':
        clear_output()
        continue
    if play.lower()=='n':
        clear_output()
        print('thanks for playing')
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total attribute of a Chips object keeps track of the number of chips in a stack.  It is initialized to 100 when a Chips is created and thereafter only changes on calls to the win_bet and lose_bet methods.

Both win_bet and lose_bet change total by self.bet.  The bet attribute is initialized to 0 at object creation and thereafter, nothing ever changes it.  So win_bet and lose_bet add 0 to or subtract 0 from self.total and the total attribute never changes.

To make it work as intended, you need to put a nonzero value into player_chips.bet at some point.  The take_bet function looks like a promising location.